# Strange behaviour reading the source HTML of an online web

Tags: android, retrofit2, httpurlconnection

I have a problem that, I guess, it's because of the objects I'm using to read a web, in this case, both `Retrofit2` and `HttpURLConnection`.

The situation is: I need to read a web without an API (not mine) and extract the whole HTML of the page, but I'm having trouble with both tools I tried (the previously mentioned) because of the web format.

The web itself has this meta tag:

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">`

so it shows the accent marks of the words with them (it's in Spanish). And you can clearly see on the web that accent marks are nicely interpreted by Chrome, Mozilla or any other browser:

[image]

You can also see the accent mark on the HTML file:

[image]

But here is when the problem stabs me on my back:

Executed:
[image]

Raw:
[image]

And now, I'll show you what I tried so far.

The first call was with `Retrofit2`.

**The client** (without any Converter, because I want it raw (that sounds bad, btw)):

```
public static Retrofit getRaiaApi() {
    if (raiaRetrofit == null) {
        raiaRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(RAIA_URL)
                .build();
    }
    return raiaRetrofit;
}
```

**The POST method**:

```
@Headers({
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8"
})
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("index.php?operacion=consulta")
Call<ResponseBody> postRaiaSearch(@Header("Cookie") String cookie, @Field("microchip") String microchip);
```

And **the call**:

```
private void nextRaiaSearch(String sessionCookie) {
    callRaiaSearch = apiInterfaceRaia.postRaiaSearch(sessionCookie, chipInput);
    callRaiaSearch.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.v("call", "onResponse");
            try {
                String html = response.body().string();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.v("call", "onFailure");
        }
    });
}
```

But that gave me, as I explained before, the HTML with those errors.

Then, I thought: "Well, maybe Retrofit is converting something and this is not really the raw source of the web, so let's try something else".

And tried it with a simple `HttpURLConnection`.

```
private void nextRaiaSearch(String sessionCookie) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("https://www.raia.es/index.php?operacion=consulta");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    OutputStreamWriter request;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", sessionCookie);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
    connection.setReadTimeout(10000);

    request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    request.write("microchip=" + chipInput);
    request.flush();
    request.close();

    String line;
    InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line).append("\n");
    }
    input.close();
    reader.close();

    String html = response.toString();
}
```

BUT, the result is exactly the same: [image]

**Am I missing something? Should I use another tool?**

Comment: The problem is the server side ... it sends chars in ISO-8859-1 but it didn't mention about it in the header ...

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that the web is from the local government, not mine, I can change nothing at all.That's why I just wanted to read the source HTML, but it don't succeded I guess.

Comment: with your `HttpUrlConnection` code try to set 2nd parameter of `InputStreamReader` constructor to force given encoding

Comment: Ok, came back and saw an answer with the same solution as this comment, and worked nicely. Thanks a lot man. Let me give you the +1 since you posted it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`InputStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) to specify the encoding offered by the server.

For example:

```
InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
```

I hope it works

Answer (score 0):

have you tried playing with the output String?

Something like

```
String html = new String(response.toString().getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I have already tried using that charset and not writing any charset at all, but the request headers change nothing on the response.

Comment: gave my answer another try

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. But when you have the response, it already has the erros, so changing the charset will do nothing on it. Thanks for the answer anyway.